# Uncaught Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException

Tags: javascript, webforms

i have this error "Uncaught Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

on webforms application please check image
image link: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nkn5V.png

Comment: Can you post the code?

Answer (score 0):

Add ScriptManager and UpdatePanel control in your html.